# Creating pairwise relationship between columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows :

```
Neighborhood, City, State, Country       

Westside, Boston, MA,USA
South District, New York,NY,USA
Business Town,,OR,USA
Shopping District,,Wellington,New Zealand
Big Mountain,,,Australia
```

Now I want to go over `pairs of NON Empty Columns` `C0,C1  C1,C2  C2,C3` and create a dataframe that looks like below. However `if C1 is empty or null then pair C0 with C2 and so on`

```
Root               Child
 OR                  Business Town
 USA                 OR
 New Zealand         Wellington
 Wellington.         Shopping District 
 Boston              Westside
 MA                  Boston
 USA                 MA
 New York            South District
 NY                  New York
 USA                 NY
 Australia          Big Mountain
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `shift` after `stack`

```
s=df.stack().iloc[::-1]
yourdf=pd.DataFrame({'Root':s.groupby(level=0).shift().values,'Child':s.values}).dropna()
yourdf
Out[62]: 
           Root              Child
1     Australia       Big Mountain
3   New Zealand         Wellington
4    Wellington  Shopping District
6           USA                 OR
7            OR      Business Town
9           USA                 NY
10           NY           New York
11     New York     South District
13          USA                 MA
14           MA             Boston
15       Boston           Westside
```

Comment: @ WeNYoBen a quick follow up , if i change ".values" to ".to_numpy()" i get the following error : "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'" . Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: @RameshK to_numpy I think this is new , can you show your pandas' version

Comment: @ WeNYoBen : '0.24.2'

Comment: @RameshK from what I can tell that is work for me under 0.25.0

Comment: @ WeNYoBen : ok , thank you.

Comment: @ WeNYoBen , can you please add a drop_duplicates() at the end. I think thats what is causing the error . I have a drop_duplicates at the end.

Comment: @RameshK sure , feel free to edit the answer :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196890/discussion-between-ramesh-k-and-wenyoben).

Answer (score 2):

#### comprehension

and other things

```
pd.DataFrame([
    t for _, g in df.stack().groupby(level=0)
    for t in zip(g.iloc[1:], g)
], columns=['Root', 'Child'])

           Root              Child
0        Boston           Westside
1            MA             Boston
2           USA                 MA
3      New York     South District
4            NY           New York
5           USA                 NY
6            OR      Business Town
7           USA                 OR
8    Wellington  Shopping District
9   New Zealand         Wellington
10    Australia       Big Mountain
```